# How do I create simple auto code generator?

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to create a simple form where people input in some values and on submit auto generates the code below the form. Which then they can copy to use.

i.e.

```
Input 1 width(px) - 200

Input 2 height(px) - 300

Input 3 content - Hello world
```

**Submit button**

```
[code to copy]

[div width="200px" height="300px"]Hello world[/div]

[/code to copy]
```

Comment: Are you trying to build/use a parser?

Comment: Thank you Jared! That's exactly what I'm trying to build. I just didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done in real time, no need to submit.

Here: http://jsfiddle.net/NzFeb/

```
$("input").keyup(function() {
    $("#result").text(
        '<div width="' + $("#width").val() + 
        'px" height="' + $("#height").val() + 
        'px">' + $("#content").val() + 
        '</div>');
});
```

To simplify the code i used the library jQuery.

- [jQuery site](http://jquery.com/)
- [How to set up jQuery in your site](http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works)

Comment: You might want to mention something about jQuery, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was after. How do I go about having multiple of these on the same page though?

Comment: Hi, one more question - How can I have it so that the result html code is displayed when the page loads, even if nothing is entered into the inputs?

Comment: Just run the function when the page load. You can instead of declare the function in the body, declare it separately `function assembleDiv() {...}` and just call it like `$("input").keyup(assembleDiv)` and on the page load `assembleDiv();`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Width: <input id="width" type="text" /> <br/><br/>
Height: <input id="height" type="text" /> <br/><br/>
Content: <input id="content" type="text" /><br/><br/>
<button id="go">Go</button><br/><br/>
<textarea id="code" cols="30" rows="10" ></textarea>
document.getElementById("go").onclick = function() {
document.getElementById("code").innerHTML = "<div style='width:" + document.getElementById("width").value+ "; height:" + document.getElementById("height").value + ";'>" + document.getElementById("content").value + "</div>";
```

};

as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/69q57/13/

Comment: @Muddles glad to help. don't forget to vote up helpful answers and mark as answer whatever you ended up going with.